# How to prove $ \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^n B_i $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ and
  $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n$ are sets such that $A_i \subseteq
  B_i$ for every $1 \le i \le n$, then
  $$ \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^n B_i $$

Comment: What kind of question is this?

Comment: Probably the reason some people have voted to close this question is that questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. They ought to explain that here in comments but usually they don't.

Comment: Homework-type questions are allowed, but the consensus is that we would like to see something more than just a problem statement. The imperative "prove that" is language that could be found on an assignment and makes it look like you just took the question from your assignment and posted it here for us to solve for you. Please read [How to ask a homework question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ and $B=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}$.

We must prove $A\subseteq B$.

Take any $a\in A$. Then $a\in A_i$ for all $i$. But then $a\in B_i$ for all $i$. But then $a \in B$.

Since $a$ is arbitrary we have $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have to prove that any given set   $A \subseteq B$  then it means that you have to prove that every element $a$ of $A$ is also an element of $B$. So for this question, let's take any arbitrary element 
$$a \in \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i$$
$$\implies a \in A_i \quad \forall  i \quad \\
As \quad A_{i} \subseteq B_{i} \quad\forall i\quad
\implies a \in B_{i}\quad\forall i $$
As $a$ is in every $B_{i}$ it must also be in their intersection i.e. 
$a\in\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}$ . Hence every element of $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ also exist in  $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}$. Hence $$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}\subseteq\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} B_{i}$$

Comment: Your argument is not correct. It will become correct if the first implication is replaced by an equivalence.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Surely the first implication is indeed an equivalence (by definition of the intersection), but you don't "need" the other way, so I wonder why this argument should be wrong.

Comment: @Jupp It is not. My mistake.